# Where to place the While loop so the loop breaks once the condition has been broken

Tags: python, while-loop

I have the following commands and variables which run as they should as it currently is. Now I need to put in a while loop that continues to run when the conditional variable is False but ends when the conditional variable is True. Where do I place it?

```
loggedIn = False

# Create a function called `getCreds` that will prompt the user for their username, password
def getCreds():

    # Prompt the user for their username and store it in a variable called username
    username = input("Username: ")

    # Prompt the user for their password and store it in a variable called password
    password = input("Password: ")

    # Create a dictionary that will store all of the user data collected inside of it and call it userInfo
    userInfo = {"username":username,"password":password}

    # Return the above dictionary (called userInfo)
    return userInfo

# Create a function called `checkLogin` that checks if the credentials match the admin list.    
def checkLogin(userInfo):

    # If userInfo matches either set of credentials in the adminList, print "YOU HAVE LOGGED IN!" and return True
    if userInfo == adminList[0] or userInfo == adminList[1]:
        print("YOU HAVE LOGGED IN!")
        loggedIn = True
        return True                

    # Otherwise, print "---------" and return False
    else:
        print("---------")
        loggedIn = False
        return False                

    # Return user
    return user

# Get user information
userInfo = getCreds()

# Create user
user = checkLogin(userInfo)
```

Comment: Can you provide more details. Like what is the conditional variable ? How are you invoking thus python script.

Comment: The conditional variable is loggedIn. To be set to False. The loop should only go when the variable is False. Should end when it’s True.

Comment: Why do you need a loop to check loggedIn ? If you are checking if the user is logged in, it would be a one time check right ?

Comment: why to loop? just use the function itself!! if your condition is true then call the function else break

Comment: I need it to loop when it’s False so it will automatically reprompt for correct admin credentials. And I need it to break when I enter in correct credentials. The idea is that it doesn’t log in without admin credentials (which I have).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way.

```
userInfo = getCreds()
loggedIn = checkLogin(userInfo)
while loggedIn:
    userInfo = getCreds()
    loggedIn = checkLogin(userInfo)
```

Or may be add another def for avoiding code duplication

```
def login():
    userInfo = getCreds()
    return checkLogin(userInfo)

while login():
    pass
```

Comment: This worked for me. I set loggedIn == to False for the while loop and it worked.

Comment: Upvote and mark the answer correct, if it worked as you wanted. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
# Get user information
while True:
    userInfo = getCreds()
    # Create user
    is_logged_in = checkLogin(userInfo)
    if is_logged_in:
        break
```

By the way, the line `return user` in your `checkLogin` function is redundant since it already returned in the if-else condition